# Angular Ionic - Detect if <ion-content> is scrolled maximum bottom

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am writing a messenger with angular and ionic. i want to fire the mothod `scrollToBottom` just if  is scrolled max bottom. Because if someone scroll top to check old messages, and the partner is sending any message, he get not kicked everytime bottom meanwhile.

This is the documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content but i cant find any that helps me to solve this.

Comment: You only need to scroll to the bottom when the owner of the chat sends a message and on entering chat, that's the behavior of a normal chat.

Comment: AND if the other guy in chat is sending a message... And in this case i want to scroll down only if the `<ion-content>` is already max scrolled bottom.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to know when the bottom is already max scrolled then you need to do something like this code:

I write some example code to achieve the goal.

Note: I'm using Angular 9 and Ionic 5 in this solution.

```html
<ion-content
  [scrollEvents]="true"
  (ionScroll)="scrolling($event)"
>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      <ion-label>Pokémon Yellow</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

```js
  import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular';

  @ViewChild(IonContent) content: IonContent;

  ngOnInit() {
    // create a list of items to show the scroll
    this.generateNumItems(100);
    setTimeout(() => {
      // after 2 secs then scroll to bottom
      this.scrollToBottom();
    }, 2000);
  }

  generateNumItems(number) {
    for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      this.items.push(i);
    }
  }

  scrolling(event: any) { // event has an interface but I don't need it
    this.detectBottom();
  }

  scrollToBottom() {
    this.content.scrollToBottom(500);
  }

  async detectBottom() {
    const scrollElement = await this.content.getScrollElement(); // get scroll element
   // calculate if max bottom was reached
    if (
      scrollElement.scrollTop ===
      scrollElement.scrollHeight - scrollElement.clientHeight
    ) {
      console.info('max bottom was reached!');
    }
  }
```